# Kubernetes: PersistentVolumeClaim error, Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have created a StorageClass and PersistentVolume but when I try to create a PersistentVolumeClaim I get the following error, "The PersistentVolumeClaim "esp-pv" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims".  I have tried to delete the StorageClass PersistentVolume, and PersistentVolumeClaim, as other posts have suggested, and then recreate the sc, pv and pvc but I get the same error.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
   name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
#volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
   name: esp-pv-volume   # name of the pv 
   namespace: espkube    # namespace where the p vis applied
   labels:
     type: local
spec:
   storageClassName: manual
   accessModes:
     - ReadWriteMany  # esp, studio and streamviewer can all write to this space
   hostPath:
     path: "/mnt/data/"
   capacity:
     storage: 10Gi  # volume size requested
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim 
metadata:
   name: esp-pv
   namespace: espkube
spec:
   storageClassName: manual
   accessModes:
     - ReadWriteMany # esp, studio and streamviewer can all write to this space
   resources:
     requests:
       storage: 10Gi  # volume size requested
```

Comment: Are you sure you deleted them fully?

Comment: I used kubectl delete pv esp-pv-volume --grace-period=0 --force, then did a kubectl get pv, and a kubectl describe and both commands returned a message saying they did not exist.  Is there another way to fully delete them?  Thanks!

Comment: That would only delete the PV, not the PVC.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the pv, the sc and can't delete the pvc, since it never binds to the pv. I am new at this. When I try to delete the pvc it can't because it doesn't exist?

Comment: $ kubectl delete pvc esp-pv --grace-period=0 --force
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "esp-pv" not found
$ kubectl get pvc
No resources found in default namespace.
$ kubectl describe pvc esp-pv
Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "esp-pv" not found

Comment: You need to give it the namespace, `kubectl delete pvc -n espkube esp-pv`. It worked for PVs because those don't use namespaces.

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue!  I can now bind the pvc to the pv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved in comments, deleting a namespaced object (which is most of them) requires specifying the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

You need to comment below in PVC or PV before deleting them, else they would remain in terminating state.

```
finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
```

to

```
  #finalizers:
  #- kubernetes.io/pv-protection
```

in order to delete pvc or pv